# SQLiteException: near "FROM": syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

I encounter an error when I compile my request.

This is my log  : android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROM": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  nom,prenom,numero, FROM  Ichar WHERE  id=?

and this is a part of my MySQLite class seems concerned by the error :

```
public Character getCharacterById(int Id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT  " +
            "nom" + "," +
            "prenom" + "," +
            "numero" + "," +
            " FROM  " + CHARACTER_TABLE
            + " WHERE  " +
            "id" + "=?";

    Character character = new Character();


    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{String.valueOf(Id)});

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            character.character_Id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
            character.nom = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nom"));
            character.prenom = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("prenom"));
            character.numero = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("numero"));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());



    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return character;
```

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Remove comma after numero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"numero" + "," +
```

->

```
"numero" +
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make query like this

```
 String query = "SELECT  " +
        "nom" + "," +
        "prenom" + "," +
        "numero" + 
        " FROM  " + CHARACTER_TABLE
        + " WHERE  " +
        "id" + "=?";
```